# Is it safe to change from structure to class

Tags: .net, vb.net

We have a structure which is widely used throughout the whole application (over one hundred times). The structure has become too complex and I'm thinking about remaking it to class.

Is it safe to migrate from structure to class?

Is this only about where the object will be stored (stack or heap) or application behavior may be broken?

Comment: Is the structure immutable?

Comment: Do you have any `where T : struct` constraints? What assumptions are being made about the struct in question?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to remember why you made it a struct in the first place. There was probably a good reason for that.

Comment: @jeroen-vannevel There are no such constraints.

Comment: It was created long ago. No one knows why it was decalred as a structure. It has become too large and also we need it to be mutable. Typical usage of this structure was: create a list of strucures -> pass somewhere  -> read all properties from every strcuture and write to DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this only about where the object will be stored (stack or heap) or
>   application behavior may be broken?

This is one concern. One more significant concern should be about the difference in the semantics between a value type and a reference type. Do you want when you assign a value of your object to assign a copy of this object or a copy of the reference, which points to an object in the heap? *This could be a big issue*. Why I say so? Wherever you pass your object, if you make it a class, you will pass a reference and any change that will be made on *at least one* of it's fields would be reflected to the object you passed and not to a copy of the object you passed. This may be an issue or not. However, in order you give a concrete answer, you have to run though your code base and look there thoroughly how your object is used. Only after doing this, you be in a position to give the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on whether the structure is actually implemented as a proper value type, or if it's implemented as a class in disguise.

If it's a proper value type, then it would be immutable (i.e. implemented as getting a value when created, which doesn't change), and you can replace it with an immutable class without changing the behaviour.

If it's mutable, then it should already have been a class in the first place. Making a class out of it will however change the behaviour.

When you assign a structure to a variable then the data in the structure is copied, but when you assing a class instance to a variable then only the reference to the instance is copied. If the code relies on the fact that assigning the values creates copies, then you need to do some rewriting.